# Angular JS two way data binding with state()

Tags: angularjs

This is an example when I define the controller.

```
.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: loginCtrl
})
```

But I found that when I use the above code instead of defining the controller in directives, there's only one way binding. Which means the data entered in the view cannot be passed back to the controller.

Is there something I did incorrect, or that's way how Angular JS data binding works?

Thanks

========================= Extra Information =========================

**The code below didn't work properly, only had one-way data binding.**

HTML File:

```
<div class="list padding">
    <label class="item item-input rounded-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
     </label>

     <label class="item item-input rounded-box">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
     </label>
</div>
```

JS File:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: LoginCtrl
    })
}
```

JS Controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";

    $scope.loginProcess = function () {

        var JSON_data = {
            email: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        };
    }
});
```

**The code below WORKS for two-way data binding.**

HTML File:

```
<div class="list padding"  ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input rounded-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
     </label>

     <label class="item item-input rounded-box">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
     </label>
</div>
```

JS File:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
    })
}
```

JS Controller (No Changes):

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";

    $scope.loginProcess = function () {

        var JSON_data = {
            email: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        };
    }
});
```

The question was why the first method doesn't work for two way data binding?

Comment: defining controllers in directives? what do you mean by that? the above code should work

Comment: <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl"></div> This works well for two way binding.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You ask why data from the view isn't being passed to the controller, but you haven't listed the code for a view or a controller to demonstrate the problem.  Then there is the fact that in your question body you use `controller: loginCtrl` and in the comments you suggest the alternate that works fine is `ng-controller="LoginCtrl"`.  These are not equivalent (note the case).

Comment: Yes, that's why I wonder why first method didn't work?

Comment: I've added more detailed code about the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data entered in the view can always be bound with the controller. All you have to do is to use $scope in the controller to define the variable and change it from the view. The last value that you will get in the controller will be updated one.

Try to implement this. You will get it clear.

Here is my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ui-view>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my index.js

```
angular.module("myApp",['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'first.html'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.username = "x";
    $scope.password = "x";

    $scope.loginProcess = function () {

        var JSON_data = {
            email: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        };
    }
});
```

Here is my first.html

```
<div class="list padding"  ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input rounded-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
     </label>

     <label class="item item-input rounded-box">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
     </label>
</div>
```

And it does bind. It binds a little late than the state() controller declaration but it does.

Here is the plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/JSMawagSsy4ucfW4SE8M?p=preview

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but it didn't work. Changes made on the view were not updated in the $scope variables. But assign values to variables through the controller function will update the view.

Comment: I gave an example. Now it shall be easy.

Comment: I understand that, my question was, why it wasn't two way data binding when I define the controller in the route state() method?

Comment: Here.. I implemented it in state(). It still works as it is suppose to.

Comment: Really? So must be something wrong with my code, I will try again, thanks

Comment: I've added more detailed code about the issue, thanks.

Comment: That is because the $scope is loaded along with transition from one state to another in state() declaration. And in the other method, the controller is loaded after the html template is loaded. Thats why it doesn't provide that binding.

Comment: So that's the way how it works? thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hey wait. It still must bind.. and it does bind. Let me update my answer

Comment: That's what I thought, the two method should have worked out the same, that's why it annoyed me so much.

Comment: It certainly works the same.. the only difference is that it has a little delay when you use ng-controller.

Comment: You may like to read the #4 [here](https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes)

Comment: and specify the controller:'LoginCtrl' in state with quotes.

Comment: Notify me when you are done with the code.. I may help you there in.

Comment: Tried again with quotes, still one way data binding. Sorry

Comment: No errors, but the data entered in the input won't be passed into the variables

Comment: hey @H.H I made a plunker just for you.. check it out... https://plnkr.co/edit/JSMawagSsy4ucfW4SE8M?p=preview

Comment: I tested the code again in plunker, both ways work well for two way data binding. I think the problem is that I use ionic framework instead of pure angularjs, and it uses ionic service, instead of the ui.router service, and it looks like that's an bug in ionic.